# Programmatically register routes at runtime

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to be able to annotate some of my controllers with @SomethingProvider so that they automatically serve `POST /{original-resource-url}/something` URL and tie this URL to a generic handler.

Using a controller with wildcard mapping would not work because not all the resources will have that "something" collection available. Ex:

```
POST /user/something
POST /product/something
etc.
```

but not

```
POST /anything/something
```

My idea is to scan my controllers at runtime and look for that `@SomethingProvider` annotation so I can programmatically register the additional "something" endpoints.

I know it has to do with `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` but I can't figure out how to tap into it to add mappings.

Thanks geniuses